# Spring Data cannot persist OptaPlanner's Score object with *ScoreHibernateType

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, optaplanner

I want to use `Spring-boot-data` to persist OptaPlanner's domain object in DB, and according to the guide, I've done the hibernate mapping task and everything looks fine except for Score object.

The score object can be persisted in DB as BLOB column if without any special configuration, but if based on the guide (17.2.1.1. JPA and Hibernate: Persisting a Score), it always throws an exception as follows:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.optaplanner.persistence.jpa.impl.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScoreHibernateType.replace(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.hibernate.type.CompositeCustomType.replace(CompositeCustomType.java:178)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:144)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:431)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:233)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:884)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:870)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.merge(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:493)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.save(Unknown Source)
at cc.tonny.optaplanner.exercise.springbootcloudbalance.CommandLineAppStartupRunner.run(CommandLineAppStartupRunner.java:64)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:818)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:802)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265)
at cc.tonny.optaplanner.exercise.springbootcloudbalance.SpringbootCloudbalanceApplication.main(SpringbootCloudbalanceApplication.java:10)
```

Please check the code at https://github.com/tonny1983/springboot-cloudbalance

Comment: `AbstractMethodError`? Please specify the version of hibernate and spring data that you are using in your classpath. Note: optaplanner `7.12.0.Final` is currently build with hibernate `5.1.15.Final`.

Comment: I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE` and it includes `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final`. So, does it mean I should exclude the hibernate-core in `spring-data-jpa` and add the dependency of `5.1.15.Final` version separately?

Comment: `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.optaplanner.persistence.jpa.impl.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScoreHibernateType.replace(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;` ... so look at that class *of yours* and see why you dont have all in the classpath

Comment: Ok, spring uses a newer hibernate version. OptaPlanner needs to upgrade its hibernate version anyway. Feel free to create a jira on issues.jboss.org (or a support ticket on access.redhat.com).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I got the problem. It is just because the one parameter's type of `nullSafeGet` method in Hibernate's `CompositeUserType` interface changed from `SessionImplementor` to `SharedSessionContractImplementor` after Hibernate 5.2.0, thus, the `AbstractScoreHibernateType` class and all its subclasses fail to implement the method then.

Comment: [Link to jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1311)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it works in `spring-boot-jpa` v2.x with `hibernate` v5.2.x, and I'll state the patch as follows:

1. Create a new class which extends `org.optaplanner.persistence.jpa.impl.score.AbstractScoreHibernateType` and implement all methods defined in the `org.hibernate.usertype.CompositeUserType` (you can copy all the code from `AbstractScoreHibernateType` but just change the parameter's type from `org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor` to `org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor`)
2. Create a new `*SoftScoreHibernateType` class which extends the one created in step 1, and add its construction method just like origin `*SoftScoreHibernateType` class
3. In my case, `getPropertyValue` method throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `levelNumbers` array only holds three items -- hard score, medium score and soft score, but the `propertyIndex` is from 1 to 3. So, I overrides the method just change the last line to `return levelNumbers[propertyIndex` **`- 1`**`];`

   That's all for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use OptaPlanner `7.18.0.Final` or later, that supports Hibernate 5.3+